# How to access Django parent model using Foreign key

Tags: django, django-models

I have this model:

```
class Cohort(models.Model):
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True,editable=True)
origin=models.BooleanField(default=False)
title = models.CharField(max_length=200,validators=[MaxLengthValidator(100)])
email = models.ForeignKey(Userdata, on_delete=models.PROTECT,default='0',db_constraint=False)


def __str__(self):
    return self.title

class Subcohort(models.Model):
cohort_id=models.ForeignKey(Cohort,on_delete=models.PROTECT,default=0,db_constraint=False,related_name='subcohortid')
parent_id=models.ForeignKey(Cohort,on_delete=models.PROTECT,default=0,db_constraint=False,related_name='subparentid')
```

From views.py I want to read Cohort model data using the subcohort cohort_id.
I want to get an object which contains cohort data along with subcohort data. Can someone help? Thank you.

Comment: try `Subcohort.objects.get(pk=subcohort_pk).cohort_id`

Comment: it saying Subcohort matching query does not exist.

Comment: Can I see your view? does it have pk of Subcohort?

Comment: I want to get Cohort data from subcohort foreign key.
I have parent_key of subcohort : parentid=Cohort.objects.filter(origin=True)[0].id
Now i want to get data of corresponding parent_key from cohort

Answer (score 1):

Do not use the suffix _id on foreign keys. The foreign key in Django is an object and not an id. Django takes care of the relationships on database level.

A `Cohort` can have multiple `Subcohort`, but a `Subcohort` can only have one `Cohort` parent.

You can get all the `Subcohort` from a `Cohort` by its related name. Your related name is `subparentid`. Which, once again, you should remove the suffix 'id' from and make it plural because a cohort can have multiple subcohorts. A better related_name would be `subcohorts`.

```py
# using your models
cohort = Cohort.objects.get(pk=pk)
subcohorts = cohort.subparentid.all()
```

EDIT:

If you have a `Subcohort` and you want to retrieve data from its `Cohort`, you can do like so:

```py
# using your models
subcohort = Subcohort.objects.get(pk=pk)
print(subcohort.parent_id.title) # prints the cohorts title
```

Comment: Thank you so much. But what if A cohort can have multiple subcohorts and a subcohort can have multiple cohorts parents?

Comment: You will need a `ManyToManyField`, meaning a `Subcohort` can have multiple `Cohorts`. You can find the documentation here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/